# How to get a sample database to play around with for SQL on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

I am currently trying to learn SQL through SoloLearn - http://www.sololearn.com/Play/SQL#.

In this tutorial, they show you how to use different commands like SHOW TABLES or SELECT * FROM [database here].

The issue is, all the default databases I appear to have lack any data for me to play around with.

In the tutorial, they're using a database with a Customer table and stuff. I don't know how they got that table/database.

How can I easily add a database filled with data that I can play around with as I follow along with this tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Ask Google for "`sample mysql database to download`" and go to one of the first pages, eg. https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx/, where you can find a sample database to download and play with.

> The *classicmodels* database is a retailer of scale models of classic
> cars database. It contains typical business data such as customers,
> products, sales orders, sales order line items, etc.

There is also a tutorial on that page explaining how to load the sample database into MySQL database server.

Have fun!